# How to apply "filters" to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

My app is currently using AVFoundation to take the raw camera data from the rear camera of an iPhone and display it on an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in real time.

My goal is to to conditionally apply simple image filters to the preview layer. The images aren't saved, so I do not need to capture the output. For example, I would like to toggle a setting that converts the video coming in on the preview layer to Black & White.

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893620/applying-effect-to-iphone-camera-preview-video) that seems to accomplish something similar by capturing the individual video frames in a buffer, applying the desired transformations, then displaying each frame as an UIImage. For several reasons, this seems like overkill for my project and I'd like to avoid any performance issues this may cause.

Is this the only way to accomplish my goal?

As I mentioned, I am not looking to capture any of the AVCaptureSession's video, merely preview it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Probably the most performant way of handling this would be to use OpenGL ES for filtering and display of these video frames.  You won't be able to do much with an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer directly, aside from adjusting its opacity when overlaid with another view or layer.

I have a sample application [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) where I grab frames from the camera and apply OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders to process the video in realtime for display.  In this application (explained in detail [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios)), I was using color-based filtering to track objects in the camera view, but others have modified this code to do some neat video processing effects.  All GPU-based filters in this application that display to the screen run at 60 FPS on my iPhone 4.

The only iOS device out there that supports video, yet doesn't have an OpenGL ES 2.0 capable GPU, is the iPhone 3G.  If you need to target that device as well, you might be able to take the base code for video capture and generation of OpenGL ES textures, and then use the filter code from Apple's [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application.  That application is built around OpenGL ES 1.1, support for which is present on all iOS devices.

However, I highly encourage looking at the use of OpenGL ES 2.0 for this, because you can pull off many more kinds of effect using shaders than you can with the fixed function OpenGL ES 1.1 pipeline.

(Edit: 2/13/2012) As an update on the above, I've now created an open source framework called [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) that encapsulates this kind of custom image filtering. It also handles capturing video and displaying it to the screen after being filtered, requiring as few as six lines of code to set all of this up. For more on the framework, you can read [my more detailed announcement](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework).

Comment: @UFO - There is a known bug with the two-pass filters and still images on iOS 7, yes. They work on live camera input and movies, but produce black images for some reason with still images on that OS. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @BradLarson is there any way i can use the cifilter(mono, tonal, noir etc) with your code?

Comment: This example code is outdated and doesnt even work on xcode 8.2

Comment: @Crashalot - What needs to be updated? If you're referring to the sample code, updating it is an exercise for the reader. The basic concepts still apply.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Just wondering if the answer is outdated or still relevant -- i.e., most performant way is OpenGL ES and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer offers little flexibility -- since the answer is over 6 years old. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at the [Rosy Writer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) example from the ios development library. Brad Larson's [GPUImage Library](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework) is pretty awesome but it seems a little overkill for this question.

If you are just interested in adding OpenGL Shaders (aka Filters) to a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` the workflow is to send the output of the capture session to an OpenGL view for rendering.

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOut = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
videoOut.videoSettings = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(_renderer.inputPixelFormat) };
[videoOut setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_videoDataOutputQueue];
```

Then in the `captureOutput:` delegate send the sample buffer to OpenGL Renderer

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef sourcePixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer );
    _renderer copyRenderedPixelBuffer:sourcePixelBuffer];
}
```

In OpenGL Renderer attach the `sourcePixelBuffer` to a texture and you can filter it within the OpenGL Shaders. The shader is a program that is run on a perpixel base. The Rosy Writer example also shows examples of using different filtering techniques other than OpenGL.

Comment: would this shader also allow you to alter the movie/video created, or only alter the preview layer?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's example [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream)  does it all

[image]

Comment: This project was a huge help in refactoring my app to use MTKView instead of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer when I decided I wanted to add filters. Thank you Apple and thank you Nick for pointing it out!