# How to implement photo effects in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to bring the photo Booth effects (twirl, squeeze, bulge) for an image?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way in OS X to apply such filters is Core Image. Core Image isn't part of the current iPhone SDK, but Apple [have announced](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/) that it'll be in iOS 5. That's currently under NDA so can't be discussed beyond the detail Apple have made public on sites such as this, but given what is public I think it'd be a very good idea to ask again or to update your question once iOS 5 is released.

In the meantime, if you want to do the effect live you're probably best off uploading the image to OpenGL and applying some sort of pixel shader, which is quite an undertaking but previous StackOverflow answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer) are likely to be helpful.

Comment: Tommy, See this link http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camwow-free-photo-booth-effects/id418368641?mt=8,http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picturebooth/id352298360?mt=8 i need to implement similar to my app.

Comment: Is this possible to implement these effects to an UIImage

Comment: I'd say it's pretty much certain that app is going the OpenGL route. They could be transforming it on the CPU but that'd be inefficient and unlikely to be very smooth. If you were coming from a UIImage, you'll likely have to upload the thing to OpenGL and process it there. It's roundabout, not very easy to implement compared to everything else in UIKit and often inefficient in terms of storage, but that's the motivation for Core Image.

Answer (score 1):

Core Image is now part of iOS 5. It has many filters you can use for creating photo effects by  simply combining them. You can use [Photo Effects SDK](http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801?ad=8699) that is built on Core Image. It comes with 35+ ready to use photo effects. You can also easily create your own photo effects with the builtin filter chaining support.