# How to get raw image data (RGB value of each pixel) from iPhone camera when using in video capture mode?

Tags: iphone, video, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession

I have to make an iPhone project that can process video data in
realtime. This app has to be able to reconize the color of the
object in the video frame. After I found information relating to
video processing in iOS, I found that I can use AVFoundation 
Framework to achieve this task but I don't know which APIs or functions 
of AVFoundation that's able to do this video processing task.

Can anyone suggest me which function to use to get image frames or
raw image data out of a video streaming in real-time?

I'd appreciate if you can give me some example code

Thank you very much for helping me...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer/5158856#5158856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first of all make use of `AVAsset` class by initiating it with your video file URL.

You can then use an `AVAssetReader` object for obtaining media data of that asset.
This will help you obtain video frames which you can read using `AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput` class object. Accessing RGB channel data from these frames is pertinent to `CGImage` classes and it's methods.

Hope this helps you to get started