# How do you display live filters in ios7?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

I'm trying to make a camera view app mimicking the ios7 camera. I want to have a live filter mode much like the native camera does, but I do not know how to access it within AVFoundations or Core Image Filter which is where the class reference is. Does anybody know how to create a view showing the 9 filters like in the native camera?

I tried looking it up online, but this is so new I couldn't find any good resources.

What I would like to know is how do you create a view to display the live filters like in the native camera? How do I access the native filters and display them with live video?

Comment: My answer to this question might be useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer . As far as presenting multiple filters at the same time, the MultiViewFilterExample in my GPUImage project I link to there does this.