# How to add distortion effect AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer() using CIFilter?

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

Can I distort the video from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer with CIBumpDistortion in Swift 2?

I tried CIBumpDistortion in a still image and it works fine.

I detected the face using Core Image and tried to distort the eyes position with a bump effect.
But, no luck. I referred the APIs and confused very much.

Comment: Good tips by Brad Larson here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5158856/2227743

Comment: @Eric Yes, I can understand from this answer but, there is no relevant code to distort eyes position.